# Android camera intent not working on some devices

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

In my app, there is a button which launches the camera intent and saves the captured image at given path. The captured image is saved when user clicks on Right mark or save option from camera.At the same time when user click on Right mark or save option from camera the onActivityResult() of Camera intent launcher activity get invoked.It's all working fine, but On some devices, the camera intent get launched on button click but when user clicks on save button after image is captured, the camera won't get closed and also its not returning to `onActivityResult()`. To launch the camera, I am using this intent.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
Log.d("PATH", path);
File myNewFolder = new File(path + "/it/Snapshots/");
myNewFolder.mkdirs();
cameraIntent.putExtra( android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(path + "/it/Snapshots/"+ic+".jpg")));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,1888);
```

Please help to solve this issue...I appreciate your valuable answers.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure /it/snaphots is writable (or exists)?

Comment: @Rob yeah not sure about writable but it will create if not exists that care taken by .mkdirs() any way its working on some devices

Comment: You may not have any external storage?

Comment: @DiscoS2 you are right thanks, that is issue. Then how to create directory on phone internal storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"tmp_avatar_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In your onActivityResult :

```
if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK)
             {             

                   Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();

                   String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                   cursor.moveToFirst();
                   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                   String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                   Log.v("log","filePath is : "+filePath);

                   cursor.close();
                   try 
                   {
                        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
                         orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+orientation, 1).show();
                        Log.v("log", "ort is "+orientation);

                   } 
                   catch (IOException e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

                   if(bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled())
                   {
                       bmp = null;               
                   }

                   File f = new File(filePath);

                   if (orientation==6)
                   {
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(90);
                        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                   }
                   else if (orientation==8)
                   {
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(270);
                        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                   }

                   else if (orientation==3)
                   {
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(180);
                        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                   }

                   else if (orientation==0)
                   {
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(0);
                        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                   }



             }
             else
             {
                 Log.v("log", "Photopicker canceled");           
             }
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer...I found issue in external storage..there were no external storage that why it was not working...Can you help me How to create directory in internal memory